# Make whole UIView clickable in nav bar button?

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm making a left bar button with a custom view (btnView). I want this view to be positioned on the edge of the screen, which Swift doesn't allow since it moves the bar button to the right if I try adding a view that's positioned further on the left. When I expand the frame to fit my UIView it simply shifts everything to fit the margin.

[image]
< the limit is set at around 15 points from the edge.

Enabling `isUserInteractionEnabled` doesn't affect the clickability of the UIView, it still responds to that small area and not the leftmost edge.

Here's my button right now:

```
func addBackButton() {
        // position of btn view on navbar
        let btnView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:-15.5, y:-6, width: 58.5, height: 44))
        // position of label in btn view
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 24.5, y: 13, width: 0, height: 0))
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = .systemBlue
        label.text = "VET"
        label.sizeToFit()
        btnView.addSubview(label)
        
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 23, weight: .medium))
        // convert UIImage to UIView
        let iconView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        // position of icon in btn view
        iconView.frame.origin.x = 5.5
        iconView.frame.origin.y = 12
        btnView.addSubview(iconView)

        // make small button to stick the view onto
        let backBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        backBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
        backBtn.addSubview(btnView)
        
        // make button clickable behind btn view
        btnView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        // convert UIButton to UIBarButtonItem and add to navbar
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn)
    }
```

I also tried adding a second button onto btnView so it could be positioned correctly, but it was still unclickable for some reason, only the nav bar button area responded.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? I want to avoid extra classes or extensions like I've seen in some of the threads, but I don't have any simpler options right now so I'm reconsidering.

Comment: you can add tapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I figured it out. You can add your view and button to your nav bar as Subviews instead of confining them to leftBarButton.

1. I added the button over my view with:

   ```
        // add button over view to perform action
    let clickableBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    clickableBtn.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 58.5, height: 44)
    clickableBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnView.addSubview(clickableBtn)
   ```
2. Removed the `isUserInteractionEnabled` and the backBtn code
3. And added the view to navbar with:

   ```
        // add btnView to navbar as subview
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(btnView)
   ```